# Edit image field javascript validation blank image not insert

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with edit image field. When click on edit link then open a page and in the page one field is image field. I want to put validation on it when image is blank then display msg of "Please enter image" and when field is not blank then not display this msg. So pls give me some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Have you even tried anything.?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to done using `Javascript`..

You have to use `alert`..

```
<script>
function checkExt() {
 if(document.mainForm.myfile.value.lastIndexOf(".jpeg")==-1) {
    alert("Please enter .jpeg image file");
    return false;
 }
}
</script>
<form name="mainForm">
<input type="file" name="myfile" onchange="checkExt();"/>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will help you!!